# How to create a custom sequence?

Tags: django

I would like to do a custom sequence such as:

I will create an object and name it as A001 if it is the first object in database.

If the object keep increasing and reach A999, the name will start over from B001. Once it reach B999, it will start from C001 again.

Comment: What did you try? what is your question?

Comment: You can do it on your `CreateView`(or some `def`) if `form.valid()`. Or by `post_save` signal.
`chr(ord('A')+1) == 'B'`. Or where you got stuck in your code?

Comment: @madzohan Yea i am doing chr(ord('A')+1) in post_save signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll offer you a simple solution here overwriting the `save` method.

Let's say we have this object:

```
import string

class YourClass(models.Model):
    alph_counter = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'Alphabet Counter'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__class__.objects.all().count() == 0:
            # First object need to be set like this
            letter =  'A'
            number = 1

            # %03d used to write the number with 2 zeros before
            self.alphcounter = '%s%03d' (letter,number)  # 'A001' this time
        else:
            # Get the last object ID
            last_id = self.__class__.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0].id + 1

            # We need to know wich letter is it, we use division over ID
            wich_letter = (last_id+1) / 1000  
            letter = string.uppercasecase( wich_letter )
            number = (last_id+1) % 1000
            self.alphcounter = '%s%03d' (letter,number)

        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks Liarez, how if i would like to do 9999 instead of 999?

Comment: You could change 1.000 for 10.000 in `(last_id+1) / 1000` and `(last_id+1) % 1000`, and also change all `%03d` for `%04d`

Comment: and the max length of the CharField `alph_counter` from 4 to 5!